# "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" In one controller test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, automated-tests

**EDIT: I've rewritten the question to reflect some of the suggestions and changes made to the code while trying to solve this problem.**

I'm trying to write an Rspec controller test, but I'm getting the following error every time:

```
Failures:

  1) AssociadosController#create quando parametros validos cria associado
     Failure/Error: @associado_params[:associado_mensalidade_attributes][:valor] = mascara_virgula_para_ponto(@associado_params[:associado_mensalidade_attributes][:valor])

     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
     # ./app/controllers/associados_controller.rb:240:in `[]'
     # ./app/controllers/associados_controller.rb:240:in `remove_mascara_valor_mensalidade'
     # ./app/controllers/associados_controller.rb:62:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/associados_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/associados_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's the full spec, as it is now (I originally posted using another syntax for declaring the parameters hash, but the end result seems to be the same. I am using `FactoryGirl`):

```
require 'rails_helper'
require './app/controllers/associados_controller.rb'

describe AssociadosController do
    describe "#create" do
        context "quando parametros validos" do
            before (:all) do
                @entidade    = create(:entidade_valida)
                @user        = create(:user, entidade_id: @entidade.id)
                @cnae            = create(:cnae)
                @solucao     = create(:solucao, entidade_id: @entidade.id)
                @mensalidade = create(:mensalidade, entidade_id: @entidade.id)
                @associado_params = attributes_for(:pessoa_juridica_valida)


                @associado_params[:associado_cnae_attributes] = [{"cnae_id" => @cnae.id}]
                @associado_params[:associado_mensalidade_attributes] = [{"mensalidade_id" => @mensalidade.id, "valor" => "0.0"}]
            end
            it "cria associado" do
                sign_in @user
                expect {
          post :create, associado: @associado_params
          }.to change {Associado.count}.by(1)
            end

        end
    end
    after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

The `associado.rb` model contains these lines:

```
has_many :associado_cnae, -> { where(status: true) }
has_one :associado_mensalidade
accepts_nested_attributes_for :associado_mensalidade, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :associado_cnae, allow_destroy: true
```

Users mahi-man and mu have given me valuable advice and definitely pointed me in the right direction, but I still can't get the test to work. It seems that the problem occurs when trying to pass nested attributes to a `has_many` association. More info on this error [here](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/29/rails-tricky-error-no-implicit-conversion-from-symbol-to-integer/):

> The issue is that the code above was seen as an array and arrays
>   cannot have named keys. Rails expected params[:user][:keys_attributes]
>   to use integers as keys (like an array does) but instead it found
>   symbols. So it was taking our symbols, trying to convert them into
>   integers, then throwing an error when it couldn’t. [...] So when Ruby
>   saw params[:user][:keys_attributes][:secret_key] it was trying to take
>   the last key and turn it into params[:user][:keys_attributes][0] or at
>   least find some integer value it could be converted to.

The solution given in the comments and in this article is to write the nested hash as an array, so instead of:

```
@associado_params[:associado_cnae_attributes] = {cnae_id: @cnae.id}
@associado_params[:associado_mensalidade_attributes] = {mensalidade_id: @mensalidade.id, valor: '0.0'}
```

It should be:

```
@associado_params[:associado_cnae_attributes] = [{"cnae_id" => @cnae.id}]
@associado_params[:associado_mensalidade_attributes] = [{"mensalidade_id" => @mensalidade.id, "valor" => "0.0"}]
```

Which I did, but I'm still getting the same error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Made the same mistake twice. This is the parameters when using an array instead of hash:

> {"associado"=>{"cpf_cnpj"=>"84.215.775/0001-74", "razao_social"=>"PESSOA JURIDICA", "nome_fantasia"=>"PESSOA JURIDICA", "dia_de_vencimento"=>"5", "status"=>true, "tipo_primario_id"=>"1", "tipo_pessoa"=>true, "telefone"=>"11111111111", "associado_cnae_attributes"=>[{"cnae_id"=>"1"}], "associado_mensalidade_attributes"=>[{"mensalidade_id"=>"1", "valor"=>"0.0"}]}, "controller"=>"associados", "action"=>"create"}

**FINAL EDIT**: I'm sorry, the solution is exactly that, but I did things without paying attention. `associado_cnae` is a `has_many` association and needs to be passed in an array, but `associado_mensalidade` is a `has_one` association and should *not* be passed as an array.

Comment: The problem can't be in the definition of `@params` as that's a valid way to define key/value pairs. _How_ you define `@params` could be a lot more clear and idiomatic but it works. You don't show what `associado_params` contains or how it's defined.

Comment: @theTinMan I added some information about `associado_params`

Comment: "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" generally means that you're trying to index an array with a symbol (i.e. `some_array[:symbol]`) so you have an array somewhere that you think you're supposed to have a hash.

Comment: As per mu's comment, but I would guess it would specifically be the nested attributes. Could you try `"associado_mensalidade_attributes"=>[{"valor"=>"0.0"}]` and `"associado_cnae_attributes"=>[{"cnae_id"=>"1"}]` i.e. make them into arrays

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. @mahi-man, your suggestion also didn't work...